# How to go back to main page in pygame?

Tags: python, button, pygame

I have a Pygame program which has a 'Home' screen that has 5 buttons which when pressed calls a new function which opens up a different screen for every different button. For every of those screens I have added a small 'Home' button at the top right so that the user can go back to the 'Home' screen from any of the called screens.

```
import pygame
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 800), pygame.RESIZABLE)

def common_screen():
    button("Home", 1400, 0, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), home_intro) **#Problem at this point**
    *#do something else too*

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,0,0))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic, (x, y, w, h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)))
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def home_intro():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                 
        window.blit(image, (0,0))
        pygame.display.set_caption("PROGRAM")
        button("Start", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), start)
        button("Screen 1", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), screen1)
        button("Screen 2", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), screen2)
        button("Stop", 550, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), stop)
        if game_state == 'screen1':
            common_screen()

        pygame.display.flip()


home_intro()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

The common_screen() function creates a 'Home' button at the top right but if I use home_intro() as the last argument in the button() function inside it, it causes a recursion error. It seems wrong to call the main function every time to go back to the main page. There is no point in creating a new function because it would be the same as the home_intro() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `home_intro` recursively, but add and call a function that changes the `game_state` variable:

```py
def home():
    global game_state
    game_state = "home" 

def common_screen():
    button("Home", 1400, 0, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), home)
```

```py
def home_intro():
    global game_state

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                 
        window.blit(image, (0,0))
        pygame.display.set_caption("PROGRAM")
        button("Start", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), start)
        button("Screen 1", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), screen1)
        button("Screen 2", 150, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), screen2)
        button("Stop", 550, 450, 100, 50, (0,200,0), (255,255,210), stop)
        if game_state == 'screen1':
            common_screen()

        pygame.display.flip()
```